# What's the term in music, where the singer uses words without meaning?

Tags: word-request, lyrics

I've been searching for the word, which is used for describing parts of lyrics, where the singer sings for example the whole refrain only using words of syllables without any meaning. Maybe you could help? (here's one song with that type of refrain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIgrwyLU3Ck)

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/374825/216106

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lexical_vocables_in_music), this phenomenon is known as ***[non-lexical vocables in music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lexical_vocables_in_music)***, and includes various styles like *doo-wop* and *scat*, as well as terms like *la la la* and *da da da*.

> Non-lexical vocables, which may be mixed with meaningful text, are a form of nonsense syllable used in a wide variety of music. A common English example would be "la la la", "na na na" or "da da da":

It can also be called ***[lilting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilting)*** in some cultures. Also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilting):

> Lilting is a form of traditional singing common in the Goidelic speaking areas of Ireland and Scotland. [...] It in some ways resembles scat singing.

Comment: I've never heard this use of ***lilting***, but +1 for ***scat***, which I'd say is the "standard" term these days.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  glossolalia? vocalization?

Answer (score 3):

The example you give is partially in English and partially in what I undestand is Gaelic: I couldn't tell you if the refrain has words in it or not:  the song *Nil 'Na Lá* is a traditional song, whose title means "Daybreak has not yet come".  https://brendannolan.com/lyrics/nilnala.html

- **Scat** is the term used for jazz non-word singing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing)
- **Lilting** is for Gaelic non-word singing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilting)
- **Yodelling** is the Alpine form of non-word singing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yodelling)

Wikipedia lists many other forms at [Non-lexical vocables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lexical_vocables_in_music).

Comment: Ok, sorry for not finding a better translation of that song. As a non-gaelic speaker, many of the words seem to me only as filling of the lyrics. I'm aware of those two styles of singing, my question was more general. Perhaps should have raised that question on some musicology website, or perhaps there really isn't any other term for it :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Aron, you can ask at https://music.stackexchange.com/ if you like.